# VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation. in NativeBase

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have attempted to implement the item picker which powered by NativeBase UI framework but I have no idea why it keeps throwing this error when I tap my item picker on the app itself. I have checked the available discussion in Stackoverflow but none of them be replied an appropriate for this issue. Meanwhile, in my code does not have VirtualizedLists at all. On the other hand, I also attach the code as below too.

I really hope someone can help me on this. Thanks.

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    RefreshControl,
    ScrollView,
    SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';
import CustomHeader from './CustomHeader';
import { Content, Button, H3, Text, Grid, Row, Card, Col, CardItem, Body, Toast, Container, Root, Icon, Item, Picker, Spinner } from 'native-base';
import axios from "axios";
import { ApiURL } from "../util/constant";
import Moment from 'moment';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { backToLogin } from "../util/auth";

class TransactionScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            accessToken: null,
            transactions: [],
            selected2: undefined,
            page: 0,
            isLoading: true,
            boolLoadMoreBtn: false,
            viewType: ['Payment', 'Refund', 'Topup']
        }
    }

    async getAccessToken() {
        token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@access_token');
        this.setState({ accessToken: token });
    }

    onValueChange2(value) {
        this.setState({ selected2: value, page: 0, isLoading: true });
        this.loadTransactionData(value, true);
    }

    loadTransactionData(whereBy = null, newView = false) {
        if (this.state.accessToken.length === 0){
            return;
        }
        const objPayload = {};
        if (whereBy != null) {
            objPayload.whereBy = whereBy;
        }
        var page = this.state.page;
        if (newView === true) {
            page = 0;
        }

        const newPage = parseInt(page) + 1;
        this.setState({ page: newPage });
        axios.post(
            `${ApiURL}/wallet/transaction?page=${newPage}`,
            objPayload,
            {
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.state.accessToken}`
                }
            }
        ).then(resp => {
            this.setState({isLoading: false});
            if (resp.status === 200) {
                const res = resp.data.transaction;
                if (newPage === 1) {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.setState({ transactions: res, boolLoadMoreBtn: true, isLoading: false });
                }
                else {
                    const r = this.state.transactions;
                    res.map(i => {
                        r.push(i);
                    })
                    this.setState({ transactions: r, boolLoadMoreBtn: true });
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.show({
                    text: resp.data.error,
                    buttonText: 'OK'
                });
                return;
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.setState({isLoading: false});
            if (error.response) {
                if (error.response.status === 401) {
                    backToLogin(this.props);
                }
                else if (error.response.status === 404){
                    if (newPage === 1){
                        this.setState({transactions:[]});
                    }
                }
                else {
                    this.setState({ boolLoadMoreBtn: false });
                }

            } else {
                Toast.show({
                    text: error.message,
                    buttonText: 'OK'
                });
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    openDetail(transactionId) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('TransactionDetail', { transactionId: transactionId, backScene: 'Transaction' });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._navListener = this.props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
            this.getAccessToken().then(() => {
                this.loadTransactionData();
            });
        });
    }

    static navigationOptions = () => ({
        headerShown: false
    })

    pullMoreData() {
        const newPage = parseInt(this.state.page) + 1;
        this.setState({ page: newPage });
        this.loadTransactionData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Root>
                <Container>
                <CustomHeader isHome={false} navigation={this.props.navigation} backScene="Home" title="Transaction" />

                <Content refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        //refresh control used for the Pull to Refresh
                        refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
                        onRefresh={() => this.loadTransactionData(this.state.selected2 === undefined ? null : this.state.selected2, true)}
                    />
                }>
                    <Item picker>
                        <Picker
                            mode="dropdown"
                            iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                            style={{ width: undefined }}
                            placeholder="All"
                            Header="Transaction Type"
                            iosHeader="Transaction Type"
                            placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
                            placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
                            selectedValue={this.state.selected2}
                            onValueChange={this.onValueChange2.bind(this)}
                        >
                            <Picker.Item label="Payment" value="Payment" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Top up" value="Topup" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Refunded" value="Refunded" />
                        </Picker>
                    </Item>
                    
                    {
                        this.state.isLoading === true ? <Spinner /> :
                        Object.keys(this.state.transactions).length > 0 ?
                            this.state.transactions.map((transaction, i) => {
                                const dt = Moment(transaction.createdAt).format('L LTS');
                                return (
                                    <TouchableOpacity key={transaction.id} onPress={() => this.openDetail(transaction.id)}>
                                        <Card key={i}>
                                            <CardItem key={transaction.id + "1"} style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: "#f8f9fa", backgroundColor: "#f8f9fa" }} header>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Row>
                                                        <Col size={55}><Text style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>{dt}</Text></Col>
                                                        <Col size={45}><Text style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}>{transaction.mode}</Text></Col>
                                                    </Row>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </CardItem>
                                            <CardItem key={transaction.id + "2"}>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Row style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>
                                                        <Col><H3>{transaction.merchant}</H3></Col>

                                                    </Row>
                                                    <Row style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>
                                                        <Col><Text style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>RM {parseFloat(transaction.amount).toFixed(2)}</Text></Col>
                                                    </Row>
                                                    <Row>
                                                        <Col><Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>S/N:{transaction.id}</Text></Col>
                                                    </Row>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </CardItem>
                                        </Card>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>

                                )
                            }) : <Card key={9999}>
                                <CardItem>
                                    <Body><Text>No Transaction is available now</Text></Body>
                                </CardItem>
                            </Card>
                    }
                    {
                        this.state.boolLoadMoreBtn === true && (
                            <Button onPress={() => this.loadTransactionData(this.state.selected2 === undefined ? null : this.state.selected2)} style={{ backgroundColor: "#f8f9fa" }} disabled={(this.boolLoadMoreBtn === true ? true : false)} light block><Text>Load More</Text></Button>
                        )
                    }
                </Content>

            </Container>
            </Root>
        );
    }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
});

export default TransactionScreen;
```

Comment: This is just a warning it takes place when we are using FlatList or SectionList inside the ScrollView Component with the same orientation.

Comment: but how can I solve this to prevent it from being shown again?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Native Base Then set the preset prop of the Screen component to fix.

for ex.

```
<Screen style={{ ...ROOT }} preset="fixed" >
```

or

you also can tell react-native to don't show a warning like this...

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: <<WARNING_STARTING_STRING>>']);
```

// Ignore all log notifications:

```
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();
```

Comment: Hi, I could not find Screen tag from Native Base library. I am not allowed to ignore the warnings in my project so I need to get it fix.

Comment: You simply have to import the LogBox from react-native and then LogBox.ignoreLogs(["VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation"]) at the starting of your app.js file.

Comment: As I said, I SHOULD NOT ignore or hide the warnings, I prefer to fix it instead of hiding the warnings.

Comment: Can you share the screen code instead of the ScrollView code only so, I can deep dive into that and help you.

Comment: pls do check my original thread and I hv updated the full source code.